# Can't find <build action> menu item in xamarin form peoject

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I try like above, but can find the menueitem
[image]

Comment: perhaps you should post a screenshot that actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: it's in the File Properties panel at the bottom right of the 2nd screenshot